# Does performing $entity->save() on field collection programmatically clears the page cache of it's node host?

Tags: 7, caching, entities, cron

I am using $entity->save() on a custom hook_cron that runs every minute. Does anyone knows if by doing $entity->save() , Drupal will clear the page cache of the nodes/views/panels housing it?

Answer (score 1):

I know that [node_form_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form_submit/7) will clear ALL page caches. Sounds like what you're looking for is something like the [expire](https://www.drupal.org/project/expire) module.

Comment: This sounds good to me. In fact, I wasn't hoping for the cache to expire. The custom module generally writes to a field collection for internal audit. Only the admins/authors are able to see this field collection in their panel pages filled with views.